# Joomla cannot insert any more article in a category

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

This time i am having a weird problem about a Joomla 1.5 website.

When I try to add new article (number 3093) to a section/category that is in the menu and then I try to retrieve it, when i call the single article page i get an error. I can't say it's a 500 error because in my hosting logs and in joomla log i can't find any trace of the error.

Even when I curl the documents what i get is an empty response.

I checked the MYSQL databases and the article are here, i tried to recover a backup of the database and everything went ok, but when i try to add the article > 3093 i cannot retrieve them.

I tried changing themes, removing mod_rewrite, debugging php and mysql, but everything is working fine, i think that something is going wrong with the controller routing.

Anyone can help, any idea or similar experience can be appreciated

Comment: have you tried a backup of the whole site (akeeba) and testing it on a different server?

Comment: I tried to reinstall in a different server and was not working too, after taking down all the components i found that was a problem with myApi, it looks like it's still calling the legacy rest api that has been deprecated, the call was throwing ["error_code"]=> string(1) "2" ["error_msg"]=> string(31) "Service temporarily unavailable" for these articles